# How to add code to a python library to it work?

Tags: python-3.x, frameworks, back-testing

i use Backtesting.py, source: https://kernc.github.io/backtesting.py/, is a Python framework:

```
from backtesting import Backtest, Strategy
```

And when i debug Its path is: **C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\backtesting**

when i add code print('it printed') into function **init** of class Backtest: and call it, i see it don't work.

Do we need to use a build command or something to let python understand that I just added the print line?

Comment: why would you alter or insert code into the `__init__` function of class Backtest ? I tested installing `backtest` package and used your import line works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

**the problem here is you are not calling the backtest class correctly**

```
from backtesting import Backtest, Strategy


class MyStrat(Strategy):

          def init(self):
        
               print('it printed')

backtest = Backtest(MyStrat, data='test_data', cash=10000)

stats = backtest.run()

print(stats)
```

**Replace 'test_data' with your actual data**